# Using Perl's DBIx::Class and doing a select where greater than on a column

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I am using the [`DBIx::Class`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class) module and I am trying to do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE column > TIMESTAMP
```

I am extremely new to Perl especially `DBIx::Class` so I really only know how to do a basic select where a column is equal to a value. How can I do it using other comparators?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DBIx::Class` uses [`SQL::Abstract`](https://metacpan.org/module/SQL::Abstract) to specify its `WHERE` clauses, so the documentation for that module is worth reading.

You will be used to things like

```
$schema->resultset('MyTable')->search({column => 42});
```

to find records with a specific valued in a column. To use a specific, non-equality operator you would use an anonymous hash that contains the operator and the value instead of just a bare value. Like this

```
$schema->resultset('MyTable')->search({column => { '>' => 42}});
```

and to use a specific SQL expression instead of a bound value you just pass a reference instead, like so

```
$schema->resultset('MyTable')->search({timestamp => { '>' => \'TIMESTAMP'}});
```

Comment: @LaurAchnid: You're welcome: it's standard procedure!

Comment: Also look at https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Helper::ResultSet::DateMethods1 which adds support for datetime related things with a RDBMS independent syntax.